# Short-commands for many German scripts

Tags: letters, scripts

I am typing a note which contains many German script letters. In particular, I need to type a German letter in capital as well as small.

I used following commands for such:

```
....

\newcommand{\R}{\mathfrak{R}}

\newcommand{\r}{\mathfrak{r}}

....

 $\R = \langle \r_1, \ldots, \r_n \rangle$ 

 ....
```

Then after running the file, it was showing error:

> Command \r already defined. \newcommand{\r}{\mathfrak{r}}

Why it makes although we defined \mathfrak{R} and \mathfrak{r} by different letters?

(Please add suitable tag for the question; frankly, I have no idea of tag; I searched for newcommand but didn't get.)

Comment: `\r` is defined already in latex it is ring accent

Comment: Ok, fine; now few things gets cleared to me. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I'd define `\fR` and `\fr` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already encountered, many single-letter command sequences are already defined, and it is a bad idea to overwrite them because this can break things at unexpected places.

So there are two possibilities:

1. Define slightly longer command (two-letter or three-letter command sequences; like the egreg suggested in the comment section). This is practicable when you use a small fixed subset of the German Script letters.
2. Define an abbreviation for `\mathfrak`, e.g. `\FR`. Note that you can drop the braces when the argument of your command consists of only one character.

To illustrate point 2, you can do something like:

```
 \newcommand*\FR{\mathfrak}
 \FR r\FR R\FR{Rr}
```

to get at the German Script characters with only a few keystrokes.

P.S. If you want to submit your work to a journal or a conference, please stick to standard LaTeX notation. Editors don't like author's macros (one reason is, that the macros of different authors are incompatible with each other; another one is the need to produce different output format like MathML from LaTeX that is broken by user-defined macros)